# gdbserver crossdebugging does not work

Tags: c, linux

Im quite new in cross compiling and cross debuggins.. so i tried to write a small programm for a router with ARM architecture.

This programm causes s segmentatiton fault so i decided to debug ist.

I configured the gcc with `--target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi` even so the gccserver but with `--host` instead of `--target`.

After that i copyied the gdbserver on my router.

To debug my programm i started the server with `"./gdbserver host:2345 geo"` where geo is my executable.
Afterwards i connect to the router with `"target remote ipAdress:2345"`.
Now the GDB gives me following error:

> Remote debugging using 192.168.42.1:2345 warning: Can not parse XML
>   target description; XML support was disabled at compile time Remote
>   'g' packet reply is too long:
>   000000002effffbe000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040feffbe00000000c0aefdb610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   0xb6fdaec0 in ?? ()

and i cant debug stepwise using the s command:
Cannot find bounds of current function

can someone help me?